# how to conditionally add a class based on text length

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following label:

```
<label class="col-md-8 boldLabel" data-bind="text: AuditorName, css: { 'border1pxsolid borderblack': AuditorName.length }"></label>
```

When I run my page, the AuditorName is populate fine, but I'm not getting the border1pxsolid borderblack styles applied.  I'm trying to get it so that if the AuditorName has a value, not a blank string, the two styles are applied to the label.

If I change the AuditorName.length condition to true==true it works.  Is there another way to check if the AuditorName field is populated then only apply those styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just bind to `AuditorName` directly as that will evaluate truthy if it's not an empty string:

```html
<label class="col-md-8 boldLabel" 
      data-bind="text: AuditorName, css: {'border1pxsolid borderblack': AuditorName}">
</label>
```

The reason it's not working as you have it is that `AuditorName` is an observable so you'd have to evaluate it to access its `length` property.  So this would also work:

```html
<label class="col-md-8 boldLabel" 
      data-bind="text: AuditorName, 
                 css: {'border1pxsolid borderblack': AuditorName().length}">
</label>
```